# Image readyState always "loading"

Tags: jquery, image

I am loading a set of images and using jQuery to test when they are complete. 1 image however displays the alternate text. I thought no big deal just test for an error, but the error is never thrown. Upon further inspection I have found that the readyState is still considered 'loading'. I dont know how to get around this.

myCode

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     setTimeout(evalImages,100);
});
$('img').error(function(){ alert('test'); });

function evalImages(){
     var imgCount = $('.myContainer img').length;
     var loaded=0;
     for(var i =0; i < imgCount; i++){
         if($('.myContainer img').get(i).complete){
              loaded++;
         }
     }
     if( loaded >= imgCount){
           ///My other logic here
     }else setTimeout(evalImages,100);
}
```

Just for this image I have opened my developer tools and done

```
 $('.myContainer img').get(7).readyState
"loading"
```

since its still loading, never complete and never errors I dont know how to test for this issue.

Update: I still do not know why this one image does not change its readyState and I am curious but as a  work around I just reveal all images after a 400 millisecond time delay.

Comment: Typo: use `setTimeout`, not `setTimeOut`.  This should have caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event

```
$(window).on('load', function(){ // ... });
```

Or, shortcut

```
$(window).load(function(){ // ... });
```

Instead of `$(document).ready`, `load` event fires after all the images are completely loaded. Also, you can use `ready` and `load` both if needed, `ready` event will fire before `load`.

Comment: Even when I remove all javascript, load the page, wait 5 minutes, open developer window and select that element manually the image in question, the readyState will still not have changed thus not triggering the events.

Comment: Not sure what have you done, check for errors in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is present in IE9 and IE10.
A simple workaround is to do a dummy img.readyState read immediately after inserting the img into DOM.


[IE9-IE10-STALE-READYSTATE.html](https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XUUR6NnBrYXFJZ0E/IE9-IE10-STALE-READYSTATE.html)
[IE9-IE10-STALE-READYSTATE.html?ie9-ie10-fix](https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XUUR6NnBrYXFJZ0E/IE9-IE10-STALE-READYSTATE.html?ie9-ie10-fix)


The bug IE11 shows with F12-debugger emulating IE9,IE10 is different from actual IE9,IE10.